# ngrx state update effect on observable behavior

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

This is **how i understand** the ngrx store: As the ngrx state is immutable, when updating it, the entire object is replaced with a new state object.

**The Question:**
When updating the state (=> creating a new state object), will all observables fire values?

```
// assume state is defined like:

interface state = {
  backendState: backendData;
  frontendState: frontendState; 
}
```

State consists of two sub-states. As state is immutable, when e.g. frontend is updated and a new state is created, will these changes on frontendState and thereby changes on state cause all observables to emmit new values?

**Context on this question:**
Recently i discussed with colleagues the way we implemented our state. They prefered a flat hierarchy and argued that changes on an objects encapsulated values would cause the enire object to be replaced in state and thereby it would be more efficient to create a flat state, using a lot of maps and string ids (not ngrx entities but similar). Thinking bout theyr arguments i wondered if there is actually a difference as you know how i understand the ngrx store/state explained at the questions beginning.

Also appreciate information about best practices in this context and an idea for a bether questions title.

**Edit 1:**
also what is the behaviour for ngrx entity, as this is an object containing an array and an object. Will entity be completly replaced?